# Message broadcasting in zeroMQ Library without forwarder

Tags: zeromq

Is there a way to do message broadcasting using zeroMQ Library without using the concept of forwarder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a PUB socket will broadcast to all connected SUB sockets. The a forwarder (a proxy) is only needed when you want to bridge different networks, e.g. from TCP to PGM multicast, or when you want to add some intelligence to the data flow, e.g. to cache recently-published messages.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the scenario where there are multiple publishers and multiple subscribers? The obvious crappy solution is to connect each subscriber to all publishers, which isn't really feasible.

Comment: Well, you're answering your own question. If you have an N-to-M problem then you either connect each of N to each of M, or you create a central point to which all Ns and all Ms can connect. You might use a multicast option (PGM) which is in effect a type of forwarder.

Comment: if you have multiple pubs and multiple subs, it is at times better to have a directory service that can setup the individual connections instead of having a single point that everyone connects to. The issue with the central point is that it creates another hop for every message... but if you're directly connected to each publisher then it is still only one hop.